# Service iphlpsvc (netsvcs) creates many short-living port forwardings

Tags: windows, port-forwarding, upnp

I discovered that one of my PCs started to request a lot short-living port forwardings according to my router (Fritz!Box 7490). Windows 10 is running on the device. It began on 25.06.2017. An update for Windows 10 was downloaded (but not installed yet) on the same day.

The PC requested a new port forwarding about every 3 minutes. Each forwarding lived for about 3 to 6 minutes. This continued for multiple hours until I stoped the PC. On the next day, the same happened after every restart for about 30 minutes. However, after this 30 minutes, no further port forwardings were requested until restarting the PC again.

The port forwardings seems to be created by the *iphlpsvc* service. At least, they refer to ports of this service. I found similar observations [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/015cfdb7-1826-4e5e-86b7-87c8335f86cc/multiple-udp-connections-for-svchostexe-netsvcs?forum=w7itprosecurity) and [here (Germann)](https://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/forum/windows_7-security/mein-rechner-schaltet-st%C3%A4ndig-%C3%BCber-upnp/9481f363-01f9-473e-8d7c-9ba42b2a4b95).

[image]

Do anyone know the reason for this behavior? I read somewhere that this service is used to automatically create IPv6 over IPv4 tunnels. Since I have native IPv6, can I dissable this service?

Comment: Do your ISP provide IPv6? If not then you may disable teredo, IPv6to4 and isatap interfaces.

Comment: @Biswa Yes, my ISP provides native IPv6. Shouldn't be any tunnel protocol redundant/unnecessary since I have native IPv6. Aren't this protocols designed to obtain IPv6 connectivity when no native IPv6 support is provided by the ISP.

Comment: Then you should have a static/dynamic IPv6 private address, isn't it?

Comment: @Biswa Yes, my PC has two global IPv6 addresses. The normal one and a temporary address.

Comment: So I advice you not to disable/delete [iphlpsvc](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/startups/iphlpsvc.dll-25881.html) service that provide [6to4](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4), [teredo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling) and [isatap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISATAP) technologies.